# Word VBA Macro to Find and Replace based on the Alt Text of an Image

Tags: image, vba, replace, ms-word

I'm looking for a Macro that will use a 'Find and replace' function but for the "alt Text" of an image.

Basically, I'd like to

- Find and image within a document based on its Alt Text
- Delete the image
- Insert a new image
- Give the new Image its own Alt Text

I've looked everywhere and I can't find anything on this, can anyone help me? I don't need any dialog boxes for this, I'd just like to enter the search and replacement criteria inside the code if possible.

Thanks in advance :)

PS: I already have code that will  go into the header of my document, insert an image then enter it's alt text value. It's the 'Find' function I'm struggling with.

```
Sub ReplaceImage()
'
' ReplaceImage Macro
'
'
If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If
If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
    ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
Selection.WholeStory
 Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
    "IMAGE_LOCATION", LinkToFile:=False, _
    SaveWithDocument:=True
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

Selection.InlineShapes(1).AlternativeText = "ALT_TEXT_VALUE"


End Sub
```

Comment: it will not work with `find >> replace` word feature. You need to have a macro which will check each object in your document. Are you talking about `InslineShapes` only (embedded shapes) or `Shapes` (floating shapes) or both which you want to process?

Comment: Thank you, I am talking about InlineShapes

Comment: I think the answer from @Manu is quite close for what you need. See my comments below the answer, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using this for a while now, I've made it even simpler

```
Dim pic as InlineShape
Dim alt as String

Alt = "ENTER ALT TEXT HERE"

For Each pic in activedocument.inlineshapes
    If pic.AlternativeText = Alt Then
        pic.Delete
Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

For searching a picture by alt text, you can use a function like this:

```
Function getPictureByAltText(altText As String) As InlineShape
    Dim shape As Variant

    For Each shape In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        If shape.AlternativeText = altText Then
            getPictureByAltText = shape
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

and use it like this:

```
Dim myPic as InlineShape
Set myPic = getPictureByAltText("YourAltText")
myPic.Delete
```

Comment: Hi Manu, thanks for this I get "Runtime Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" And Debug takes me to the line "myPic.Delete" Any ideas?

Comment: possibly one `set instruction` is missing in this line: `set getPictureByAltText = shape`

Comment: BTW, +1 for quite nice solution using `function`.

Comment: Many thanks Manu and @KazJaw for your suggestions, I really appreciate the help (Sorry I can only tag one user. I am however having the same RunTime error after including the extra `set`. It now looks like: `set getPictureByAltText = shape`

Comment: check if there is any object or if function is returning nothing.

Comment: @KazJaw - The Variable (myPic) is returning nothing. Used this handy bit of code to get that info 

`If myPic Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "myPic is returning Nothing."
Else
    MsgBox "myPic is returning something."
End If`

Comment: which means that there isn't any `inlineshape` with the alter text you used as function parameter. Is it correct?

Comment: @KazJaw (Sorry this is getting so long.) Hmmmm... I have an image (as an InLineShape) in my document with the alt text "test123". In the Code I am including this: `Set myPic = getPictureByAltText("test123")` (the rest is as above) and then running the code. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you sure it's `inlineshape`? what if you check in immediate window for `? activedocument.inlineshapes.count` ?

Comment: @KazJaw `activedocument.inlineshapes.count` returns 1 :( (and yes, there's only one image in the file :P)

Comment: what if you change `thisdocument` into `activedocument` inside your code??

Comment: Unbelievable. That was the problem this whole time and I can't believe I didn't try that myself. Thanks SO much you're both absolute legends!!!!

Comment: Thanks KazJaw for figuring out the problem! :)

Answer (score 2):

So with the Help of [Manu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2829009/manu) and [KazJaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2143262/kazjaw) We got to the bottom of this.

Here is the correct and working code with my own additions to fight off errors :)

```
Function getPictureByAltText(altText As String) As InlineShape
Dim shape As Variant

For Each shape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If shape.AlternativeText = altText Then
        Set getPictureByAltText = shape
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Then:

```
Sub DeletePicByAltText()

Dim myPic As InlineShape
Set myPic = getPictureByAltText("ENTER ALT TEXT YOU ARE SEARCHING FOR HERE")
If myPic Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Your Picture was not found. Check the 'Alt Text' is correct and try again."
    End If
On Error Resume Next
myPic.Delete

End Sub
```

Thanks again for all your help!